# how to use php to save old array and also show the new arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

I have two text boxes for first and last name and I want the first and last name to print out after submitting.

I wonder if there's an easy to to print out old and new arrays I entered....
for example:
I entered ABC ABC then after submitting it shows ABC ABC then I reload the page and type in CCC CCC and submitting but this time the print out is ABC ABC CCC CCC.

how can I do that?
this is what I have for my html scripts

```
    <form action = "./3.php" method = "get">
        First name:     <input type = "text" name = "firstname">
        Last name:  <input type = "text" name = "lastname">
                <input type = "submit">
    </form>
```

this is my php scripts

```
<?php
$array = array($_GET["firstname"],$_GET["lastname"]);

foreach($array as $info)
{
    echo $info . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you have to store the data 'somewhere' between instances (http being stateless) looks like sessions would work ok for this.

Comment: thanks everyone....I thought there might be a way without database/file handlers...hehe ^_^

Comment: There is. You can stuff the old data in hidden variables in the form.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `$_SESSION[]` to store values so that you can use it again until you done.

*note: Using sessions may have effect that every time youre want your transactionsto be finish you must destroy session..*

Answer (score 0):

you may store the values in a table [firstname, lastname]. 
And every time you submit

1. insert new values
2. read all the values from the table.
3. display

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers:

What you are looking for is called persistent data. You need some data to exist over a longer period of time than just an HTTP request (a page load). In order to do that, you have to store the data somewhere more permanent.

There are a few ways you can do this.

- You can store the data in a database.
- You can store the data in a file.
- You can store the data in a cookie/session.

You're looking for the simplest and easiest solution - and that would be cookies/sessions. PHP offers built-in methods for dealing with cookies and sessions.

Using cookies/sessions is very similar to just creating a variable and storing the value you need in it, except that PHP saves this data onto a file (either on the client's machine or your server) and loads the data into the variables for you automatically before the script starts, so you don't have to think much about how to handle the file that's created.

In PHP, here's an example using cookies:

```
setcookie('TestCookie', $value, time()+3600*24);
```

This creates a cookie (a small file) on the client's machine, names it "TestCookie", stores the contents of `$value` in the file, and saves the file. PHP will automatically load that file into a global array named `$_COOKIE`, which you can use on any script in that domain e.g. `www.domain.com` for the next 24 hours.

```
echo $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
```

Sessions work very similar to this, except they store the file on the server, which is a more secure, but slightly more complicated process.